# CSS background-image and safari aren't playing nicely, won't even show up in debugger

Tags: css, safari, background-image, background-color

Ive got this site I'm working on, trying to make it responsive, and so I have this div ID that appears once a certain width is met on a mobile device, here is the CSS

```
#mobilenavbuttons1 {
max-width: 750px;
padding-top: 20%;
height:0;
background: url("../../../images/productcatalog.jpg") repeat-x 0 0 / 100% auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;  
padding-bottom:3px;
margin-bottom:4px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
}
```

This button shows up in every browser, even chrome, but when I open it in safari, its just empty where it should be. I try using the debug tool in safari and i can't even see the image background being loaded when I glance at the styles section of the debugger.

I've read tons of articles and posts on Stackoverflow about this but none of the solutions have worked. I've tried png, gif, quotes, no quotes (around the image), even putting the background size on another line and not in the same call as the image, nothing has worked. any thoughts?

Comment: Are you missing the standard `background-size: cover;` ?

Comment: No I tried that too but I took it out, made my image look slightly off, like it pushed it a bit to the right. either way it didn't make a difference in safari

Comment: Have a snippet of the applied html, fiddle, or maybe a link to the page to peek at?

Comment: Im working in a WAMP environment at the moment so I dont have a link. all I can show for the html is:

<a href="/products" id="mobilenavbuttons1"></a>

Comment: Does everything else in the media query work? I've found that if you're missing a } in safari, anything after that will break.

Comment: Yes the media queries work, I have a slider, a header, all of those work fine....just these images don't show up, but the space for them is still there too. its bizarre.

Comment: What's the size of the actual image? is there any other styles it's inheriting from global styles? like for something for it's base `width` for example?

Comment: I figured it out guys, see the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured a solution, I think it has something to do with that backslash/format of how I wrote it on one line. this does the trick though:

```
#mobilenavbuttons1 {
display: none;
max-width: 750px;
padding-top: 20%;
height:0;
background: url("../../../images/productcatalog.jpg") rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-size: 100% auto;
background-repeat: repeat x 0 0;
padding-bottom:3px;
margin-bottom:4px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
}
```